# What is wrong with these sentences?

Tags: mysql, sql

my sql command

```
ALTER TABLE orders
ADD size varchar(255),
    CHECK(size in ('s','m','l','xl'));
```

Comment: What output do you get when running this query?

Answer (score 1):

MySql expect the check directly after the declaration of the column, so if you remove the comma everything works sine

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD size varchar(255) CHECK(size in ('s','m','l','xl'));
```